# Dynamically creating an SQL query with many ANDs and ORs

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, database-design

I have a .NET Forms application that is a tracking system for manufacturing. I have a DataGridView and several ListViews with checkable items to filter the data table. Filters include part number, charge number, current location, etc. There are 9 ListViews and 2 TextBoxes (inputs are heavily checked). Right now I am using a For loop on the checked items to add them to the Where clause of an SQL query. I am worried that my queries might become very inefficient. 
The query includes 13 joins and the main table I am querying has about 2,000 rows, but I can see it getting to 100,000 over the next few years.

```
string query = @"SELECT top 1000 [column names] FROM [table names and joins] ";  

List<string> filters = new List<string>();

//
// Part Number 
//
if (ListViewPartNumber.CheckedItems.Count != 0)
{
    string PartNumberFilterString = " ( ";
    for (int i = 0; i < ListViewPartNumber.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
    {
        int PN_ID = ListViewPartNumber.GetCheckedValue( i );
        PartNumberFilterString += "SubAssembliesTable.PN_ID  = " + PN_ID;
        if ( i < ListViewPartNumber.CheckedItems.Count - 1 ) 
            PartNumberFilterString += " OR ";
    }
    PartNumberFilterString += " ) ";
    filters.Add(PartNumberFilterString);
}
```

It adds to the filter list for each listview that has items checked. Then it combines them into one string for the database query.

```
//
// Create filter string
//
for ( int i = 0 ; i < filters.Count ; i++ )
{
    if ( i == 0 ) query += "\r\n where ";
    query += filters[ i ];
    if ( i < filters.Count - 1 ) query += " AND ";
}

query += " \r\nORDER BY [ColumnName]  desc ";
```

It works fine, I haven't noticed any performance issues, but I am worried that I am doing this the completely wrong way. The query could end up with dozens of ANDs and ORs.

Comment: Why not create a test table with 250k records and run the queries against that? Then you'll know whether it's a problem or not.

Comment: This sounds more like a Database Design then a C# question. I added the respective tags. But really, we need some information on how the table looks to give any actually advice. If your server supports it, you can turn some of the more common combinations into a View. That would keep the query readable, and would allow the Server do to sensible caching without running into out-of-date data. But if you got **thirteen** joins, somethjing sounds very wrong.

Comment: @Christopher I think you are right about using a view to eliminate all of the joins. But, that wouldn't solve the problem of all of the ANDs and ORs in the where clause.

Comment: @MikePennie basically you could build your own query and translate them to SQL string query, it might spend time but it's interested. Check Azure Storage Table query builder `TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "RawMaterial");` [Read more](https://vkinfotek.com/azureqa/how-do-i-query-azure-table-storage-using-tablequery-class.html). Otherwise, finding 3rd party [SQL query builder](https://github.com/sqlkata/querybuilder) for time-saving

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the list boxes contain the lines of multiple reference tables

- check that corresponding foreign keys columns are indexed (excluding non-selective columns like "sex" or "enabled" which have 2-3 unique values)
- use the code snippets like `SubAssembliesTable.PN_ID IN (id1, id2, .. idN)` instead of `SubAssembliesTable.PN_ID=id1 OR SubAssembliesTable.PN_ID=id2 ...`
- use rather query parameters to avoid SQL injection attack
- add some performance tests to ensure required response time in concurrent mode

You can also have a look on "[Programming with databases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2956300806)" book which contains more detailed explanations on the topics above.